# Do any scripture tell us of Lord Vishnu giving boon to asuras?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, asuras

In puranas, we frequently see Lord Shiva or Lord Brahma giving boon to some danava or daitya for their austerities which usually causes some problem in future which needs to be solved in some inventive way. Has Lord Vishnu also given such a boon to any danava or daitya which lead to trouble afterwards?

Comment: The gayasura got boon from Lord Vishnu. But i don't think that he created any chaos after getting that boon.

Comment: @rickross I think mahabali also got boon of becoming next Indra and having Vishnu as door keeper. Did not create any trouble after that.

Comment: @Aks Jalandhara made Lord Vishnu to stay with him.

Comment: @the destroyer Yes, though Jalandhara powers were because of he being son of Shiva and he does not seem to have done austerities as such to get those powers, but Lord Vishnu's boon indeed removed only obstacle (Vishnu himself) in his path to conquest of swarga. Let us see if anyone knows classic austerities -> boon -> chaos example. Otherwise this is closest example we have of Vishnu's boon leading to upheaval.

Comment: Daksha (son of Brahma and not a Asura) got a boon from Lord Vishnu (Lord Vishnu will fight from his side) same as Banasur got from Lord Shiv. Both caused the trouble : 1. war between Lord Vishnu and Veerbhadra (a gana of Lord Shiv) 2. war between Lord Shiv and Lord Krishna (avtar of Lord Vishnu). As mentioned by others Asuras Bali and  Jalandhar requested Lord Vishnu to stay with him which caused little unbalance in universe. Other Asura who got boon from Lord Vishnu is Prahlad but didn't cause any trouble.